# How to add image in a given directory to carousel

Tags: html, ruby, carousel, haml

I have this carousel code, which works fine, but its images are pointing o external links. I would like to point to some directory instead, however I can't get it to work.

I've tried:

```
.item.active
            %img{:alt => "", :src => "/images/img1.jpg"}/
.item
            %img{:alt => "", :src => "/images/img2.jpg"}/
.item
            %img{:alt => "", :src => "/images/img3.jpg"}/
```

```
%div{class: 'col-xs-12 col-sm-12'}
%section#carousel
  .row
    .col-md-12
      #myCarousel.carousel.slide
        %ol.carousel-indicators
          %li.active{"data-slide-to" => "0", "data-target" => "#myCarousel"}
          %li{"data-slide-to" => "1", "data-target" => "#myCarousel"}
          %li{"data-slide-to" => "2", "data-target" => "#myCarousel"}
        / Carousel items
        .carousel-inner
          .item.active
            %img{:alt => "", :src => "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/67/London_Eye_%281302205182%29.jpg/1024px-London_Eye_%281302205182%29.jpg"}/
          .item
            %img{:alt => "", :src => "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Buckingham_palace_london_2004-09-05.JPG"}/
          .item
            %img{:alt => "", :src => "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Queens%27_Building%2C_Queen_Mary_University_of_London.jpg"}/
```

But the images aren't loaded. What can I do to make it work?